# Weak Convergence for ALL bounded, continuous functions

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

The question might be really trivial, but it always confuses me.

A way of proving weak convergence between two distributions $\mathbb{P}_{n}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is by showing that

$$\int_{S} f d\mathbb{P}_{n} \rightarrow \int_{S} f d\mathbb{P}  \ \ (*)$$

for all bounded, continuous real valued functions $f$ on $S$

---

However, it is stated for $\textbf{all}$ such functions, how to we find $\textbf{all}$ these functions? Is it ever possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you mean by "find all these functions"?

Comment: @bitesizebo  For example, if we have a space $S$ which has only two functions bounded and continuous, $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ then we would try to prove the converge $(*)$ first for the $f_{1}$ and then for the $f_{2}$.

Comment: In the case were there are hundreds of such functions, how we prove weak convergence based on the $(*)$?

Comment: Let's consider a more simple convergence. To prove, for a real sequence, that $x_n \to x$ we need to show for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\lvert x_n - x \rvert < \epsilon$. There are infinitely many such $\epsilon > 0$, yet we can still prove a sequence converges using this definition. The same is true here, there will be infinitely many such functions, but we can still show something holds for all of them without proving it one-by-one for each function.

Comment: @bitesizebo You unarmed me, I've never thought it that way!!